# Have Image Title Text on top of Image

Tags: jquery, html, css

Images have the title attribute. But is it possible to have that title visible above the image? That is, without additional elements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>You could do something like this in CSS:</strike>

```css
img:before {
   content: attr(title);
   display: block;
}
```

Or if you can use jQuery - [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WjhW6/1/):

```js
$('img').before(function(){ return this.title });
```

**Update:** It seems as if most browsers do not support the `:before` or `:after` pseudo tag on images. So your best bet is going with the jQuery.

Comment: The jQuery version only works properly for the first selected `img` element. `$('img').before(function(){ return this.title })`

Comment: @undefined - That worked, but I can't style it? The title shows up outside the img tag, with no tags of its own.

Comment: @Jason Well, it is a textNode, you can't style the textNodes, create an element, `return "<span class='style_it'>" + this.title + "</span>"`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use CSS like this example.

```
<style type="text/css">

  a.hovertext {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    text-align: center;
  }
  a.hovertext:after {
    content: attr(title);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0.5em 20px;
    width: 460px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    text-decoration: none !important;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s;
    -o-transition: 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: 0.5s;
  }
  a.hovertext:hover:after, a.hovertext:focus:after {
    opacity: 1.0;
  }

</style>

<p><a class="hovertext" href="#" title="The title attribute of the link appears over the image on hover"><img src="/images/css_textoverimage.jpg" width="500" height="309" border="0" alt=""></a></p>
```

Whit this you can use the title attr.

A better explanation is here: [http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/textoverimage/#.UjzkuWTN63M](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/textoverimage/#.UjzlKWTN63M)

Comment: The OP asked to do it *without* extra elements (ie. image tag only).